# Python: using loops with lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say I have a list:

```
list1=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,0,11]]
```

1. I want to print all the elements of the sublists. How do I write the code for it, using loops?
2. I know how to find the sum of one sublist of a list.
   Similarly I want to find the sum of all the sublists, basically the sum of `list1`.

How do I write the code for that?

Here's the code I tried:

```
a=[[1,2,3], [1,5,4], [2,4,5]]
i = 0
sum = 0
b=a[1]
while ( i < len(b) ) :
 sum = sum + b[i]
 i = i + 1
print ( sum )

a=[[1,2,3], [1,5,4], [2,4,5]]
i = 0
sum = 0
c=a[2]
while ( i < len(c) ) :
 sum = sum + c[i]
 i = i + 1 
print ( sum )

a=[[1,2,3], [1,5,4], [2,4,5]]
i = 0
sum = 0
d=a[0]
while ( i < len(d) ) :
 sum = sum + d[i]
 i = i + 1
print ( sum )
```

The output:

```
10
11
6
```

I want to find the sum of the given numbers. How do I modify the code?
I'm using python3. Loops to be used: `while` and `for`.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes. I did try to assign the sum of each element from the main list to a different variable and then find the sum. I'm not able to operate the addition of all the sum and then print it.

Comment: For individual sum try a = [sum(each) for each in list1] and to get sum of all values, do sum(a)

Comment: I understood how to find the sum of an single sublist.

Comment: I , have put up the code I tried. Changes can be added here.

Comment: Put a loop around your loops could work

Comment: @user1655072: Not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you are declaring a variable called **sum** that is overriding a Python built-it function by the same name. Once you do that the **sum()** function won't be available in that instance of Python.

Keep in mind that lists are iterable. So to get each sublist:

```
list1=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,0,11]]

for sublist in list1:
    print(sublist)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[8, 9, 0, 11]
```

You could print out each element individually:

```
for sublist in list1:
    print(*sublist)

1 2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9 0 11
```

Or print a newline after each element:

```
for sublist in list1:
    print(*sublist, sep='\n')

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
11
```

Since a list is iterable it can be summed using the built-in function **sum()**.
Which one is easier to read?

```
my_sum = sum(sublist)
```

OR

```
my_sum = 0
for number in sublist:
    my_sum += number
```

You could keep track of each sublists' sum in a variable declared outside of the loop.

```
sums = 0
for sublist in list1:
    sums += sum(sublist)
print(sums)

56
```